# Javascript groupby sum giving wrong results

Tags: javascript, group-by, lodash

I have this list of dictionaries **data** I want to apply groupby and then do **sum of amount** but I am getting **end_date** as `2020-05-11 00:00:00+00` instead of `2020-05-17 00:00:00+00` in the final aggregation

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

**Input data :-**

```
data = [
{start_date: "2020-05-11 00:00:00+00", end_date: "2020-05-17 00:00:00+00", id: "ola", amount: 10},
{start_date: "2020-05-11 00:00:00+00", end_date: "2020-05-17 00:00:00+00", id: "ola", amount: 2}
]
```

**Expected result :-**

```
start_date: "2020-05-11 00:00:00+00", end_date: "2020-05-17 00:00:00+00", amount: 12}
```

**Current Result :-**

```
start_date: "2020-05-11 00:00:00+00", end_date: "2020-05-11 00:00:00+00", amount: 12}
```

**groupby formula :-**

```
var result = _(data)
            .groupBy(x => x.start_date, y => y.end_date)
            .map((value, key) => ({start_date: key, end_date : key, amount: _.sumBy(value, 'amount')}))
            .value();
```

If there is any other solution with Javascript, Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: So threre are different start and end dates? Are they linked by id?

Comment: Lets ignore the `id` . now I want to groupby start_date and end_date(which will be different) and then perform the sum for the `amount`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are chaining `data`, so the next `groupBy` just have to take one param (which is *The iteratee to transform keys* in the [doc](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy))

You could make group key of combination of `start_date` and `end_date`

```js
const data = [
  {
    start_date: "2020-05-11 00:00:00+00",
    end_date: "2020-05-17 00:00:00+00",
    id: "ola",
    amount: 10,
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-05-11 00:00:00+00",
    end_date: "2020-05-17 00:00:00+00",
    id: "ola",
    amount: 2,
  },
]

const result = _(data)
  .groupBy((obj) => [obj.start_date, obj.end_date].join("to"))
  .map((value, key) => ({
    start_date: key.split("to")[0],
    end_date: key.split("to")[1],
    amount: _.sumBy(value, "amount"),
  }))
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple reduce loop using start and end as the key

```js
data = [{
    start_date: "2020-05-11 00:00:00+00",
    end_date: "2020-05-17 00:00:00+00",
    id: "ola",
    amount: 10
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-05-11 00:00:00+00",
    end_date: "2020-05-17 00:00:00+00",
    id: "ola",
    amount: 2
  }
]


const groupIt = data => {
  const groupings = data.reduce((grps, item) => {
    const { start_date, end_date, amount } = item;
    const key = `${start_date}-${end_date}`;
    grps[key] = grps[key] || { start_date, end_date, amount: 0 };
    grps[key].amount += amount;
    return grps;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(groupings);
}

const result = groupIt(data);
console.log(result);
```